# Switching letters in words C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char main[10000] = {0};
    cin.getline(main, 10000);
    char clone [10000] = {0};
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    for (int z = 0 ; z < strlen(main); z++) {
        if (main[z] == '.' || main[z] == ',' || main[z] == ' ' || main[z] =='"' ||
            main[z] == '!' || main[z] == '?' || main [z] == ';')
            counter2++;
    }

    if (counter2 == 0) {
            if (strlen(main) < n) {
                n = n % strlen(main);
            }

            int b = strlen(main);

            for (int x = b - n; x < b  ; x++) {
                cout << main[x];
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < x - n; y++) {
                cout << main[y];
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(main); i++) {
        clone[counter] = main[i];

        if(main[i] == '.' || main[i] == ',' || main[i] == ' ' || main[i] =='"' ||
           main[i] == '!' || main[i] == '?' || main [i] == ';') {

                int a = strlen(clone);

                if (counter < n) {
                    n = n % counter;
                }

                for (int x = a - n - 1; x < a - 1; x++) {
                    cout << clone[x];
                }

                for (int y = 0; y < x - n; y++) {
                    cout << clone[y];
                }
                cout << main[i];
                counter = 0;

                for (int z = 0; z < a; z++) {
                clone[z] = '\0';
                }
               }

           else {
                counter++;
           }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm working on a project that switches letters in words. For example the word funny when n = 3 will output nnyfu. It just moves all letters n-times. However when I try to do this with a long sentence containing a character different than a letter and follow it with another char of the same type (for example a coma followed by space) the program seems to crash. I'm wondering if anyone can help me with this because I've been pulling my hair out all day long. Also it mustn't be necessary for an input with a couple of words to end with a char different than a letter but I can't seem to figure it out too (for example inputting "Hello my friends" and n = 3 it will output "lloHe ym).

Comment: Read the input into a `std::string`, split the string into words (punctuation becomes its own word), use `std::rotate` on each word and then stitch it all back together.

Comment: And read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.  You can then find the problem yourself.

Comment: Also, don't call the char array `main` inside function `main` - I *think* the compiler will understand - but humans will get confused, and if the compiler does get confused, it will get *very* confused

Comment: But is there a way to fix the program without using strings?

Comment: Sure, anything can be fixed.  But you need to know where it crashes.  Did your debugging not pin it down?